# DRF request.data has no attribute _mutable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-oauth

I'm using Django 2.x and Django REST framework.

I'm using `django-oauth-toolkit` to enable `OAuth2` authentication and `django-rest-auth` for login and `django-allauth` for user registration.

I want to generate access token in the response when a user is successfully registered. For that, I'm using a custom registration view.

For that, I have created a function utils like

```
def generate_token(request, user):
    # Get OAuth application to use
    application_: Application = Application.objects.filter(
        client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
        authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_PASSWORD
    ).first()

    if not application_:
        raise Exception('No OAuth2 Application is setup')

    auth_data = {
        'username': user.username,
        'password': password,
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': application_.client_id,
        'client_secret': application_.client_secret
    }

    if request.data:

        mutable = request.data._mutable
        request.data._mutable = True
        request.data.update(auth_data)
        request.data._mutable = mutable

    if request.POST:
        mutable = request.POST._mutable
        request.POST._mutable = True
        request.POST.update(auth_data)
        request.POST._mutable = mutable

    return TokenView().create_token_response(request=request)
```

When the endpoint is hit by **Postman** it works fine and `request.data` has `_mutable` attribute.

But when it is hit by Angular application, it gives error

```
'dict' object has no attribute '_mutable'
```

and the error points to `mutable = request.data._mutable`

Why `_mutable` is missing for some requests?

> Edit 2: Request headers

The request header sent by **Postman** is

```
Content-Type:"application/json"
Accept:"application/json, text/plain, /"
User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
Cache-Control:"no-cache"
Postman-Token:"b4461728-a6a9-48da-a4fa-3894920b5484"
Host:"api.staging.scanova.io"
Cookie:"messages="660481c3ce8c48b1884641ffdec0a3f701cdc9cf$..."; csrftoken=tNa6o6RDkEUTBti1cDJCvgV5oLG84qczgADeDfSY7hROsLP6cmhIgQKaamPQU7Xy; sessionid=r0l8kh58n8i14quyemj60ur6i59uhy1i"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Content-Length:635
Connection:"keep-alive"
```

The request header from Angular is

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: false false
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:4200
Referer: https://localhost:4200/auth/register
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36
```

> Edit 3: Request type

The main view which is called from the endpoint is `CreateAPIView`. `generate_token` is called from this view which uses `TokenView` to generate an access token. The `TokenView` use Django's generic `View`.

Comment: What HTTP type request do you execute in angular? GET, POST etc.?

Comment: its `POST`. Updated question with the request headers in both scenario.

Comment: What is the type of your ```request``` object? Django's ```HttpRequest``` or DRF's ```Request```?

Comment: Since the request is going through REST framework, its DRF's `Request`. If it would be `HttpRequest` then `request.POST` will work instead of `request.data`

Comment: I mean, what type is your ```TokenView```? I'm guessing that you need to switch your if statements and edit ```if request.data``` as ```elif request.data``` because the request you are getting might be type of django's ```HttpRequest```.

Comment: But same code is working from **Postman** then why not from **Angular**? Is there something missing in the request?

Comment: The only difference I can see is your ```content-type```. Can you modify your angular request so that it has ```content-type``` header exactly as ```application/json``` only?

Comment: No, even `content-type` is same in both set to `application/json`.

Comment: @AnujTBE Would you print `request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE')` on the django function and test from both postman and Angular?

Comment: The Postman content type is `multipart/form-data` while the Angular's is `application/json`. It seems this is the main issue. But Postman's console is saying the Content-Type header is `application/json`

Answer (score 6):

For posterity (even though the question is rather old):

It seems like django/DRF treats `multipart/form-data` and `application/json` content type in a different enough way to cause issues.

So, even when using the same endpoint(viewset) and depending on whether the form is sent as multipart or app/json - `request.data` will be a different object.

In one case it would be a 'normal' dict while in other it would be of `QueryDict` type. So, in order to use the hacky `_mutable` on/off an additional check similar to this is needed:

```
...
# one can also use:
# if 'multipart/form-data' in request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE'):
# instead of the condition below
if isinstance(request.data, QueryDict):
  auth_data = json.dumps(auth_data) # <----- QueryDict expects string values

request.POST._mutable = True # <----- mutable needs to be modified on POST and not on data
request.data.update(auth_data)
request.POST._mutable = False
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I used (request.POST._mutable = True) and this way does not work for me.
then I copied request.POST in a new variable and I use the new variable in whole my code and this way work fine